# Trouble with scaling - CSS

Tags: html, css

Im having trouble figuring out how to fix the issue of my images moving up the screen when i resize the browser vertically. Also not only do my images move up the screen but my banner's text and background also move around which causes the banners text to move off the banner.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>A-level Revision Website</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <h1>A-Level Revision Website</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <form id="loginForm">
            <input type="email" class="login-username" autofocus="true" required="true" placeholder="Email" /><br>
            <input type="password" class="login-password" required="true" placeholder="Password" /><br>
            <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" class="login-submit" /><br>
            <a href="#" class="login-forgot-pass">forgot password?</a>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="imagesMain">
        <a href="Maths.html">
            <img src="images/Maths.jpg" alt="Maths">
        </a>
        <a href="ComputerScience.html">  
            <img src="images/Computer_Science.jpg" alt="ComputerScience">
        </a>
        <a href="Physics.html">  
            <img src="images/Physics.jpg" alt="Physics">
        </a>
    </div>
</html>

.banner{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #595959;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 180px;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
}

#imagesMain{
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 75rem;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#imagesMain a{
  width:30%;
  float:left;
  position:relative;
  margin:1.5%;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

body, html {   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display:table;
}
body {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
form {
    display:table;
    margin:auto;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/zntzep48/7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The banner's text isn't moving relative to the screen but the gray background is moving because you set it to 25% of the screen height. When you adjust the height of the window, the banner adjusts accordingly. Just remove the height property altogether. Remove the line-height and set padding-top. Set the banner to position relative cause its covering up the form.

Add

```
#form {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

and change form's div to that id. Remove the table-cell table-display you put in the body and html.

Change #imagesMain to position: relative.

Working solution:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>A-level Revision Website</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<style>
.banner{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #595959;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 50px;
}

#imagesMain{
    position: relative;
    max-width: 75rem;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 20px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#imagesMain a{
  width:24%;
  float:left;
  margin:1.5%;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-right: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom:0;
}

body, html {   
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
#form {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 50%;
}
</style>

<body>
    <div class="banner">
        <h1>A-Level Revision Website</h1>
    </div>

    <div id="form">
        <form id="loginForm">
            <input type="email" class="login-username" autofocus="true" required="true" placeholder="Email" /><br>
            <input type="password" class="login-password" required="true" placeholder="Password" /><br>
            <input type="submit" name="Login" value="Login" class="login-submit" /><br>
            <a href="#" class="login-forgot-pass">forgot password?</a>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="imagesMain">
        <a href="Maths.html">
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/9a/c8/069ac81cbe0e3a6f8fb43a0df42125a0.jpg" alt="Maths"">
    </a>
        <a href="ComputerScience.html">  
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/9a/c8/069ac81cbe0e3a6f8fb43a0df42125a0.jpg" alt="ComputerScience">
    </a>
        <a href="Physics.html">  
            <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/06/9a/c8/069ac81cbe0e3a6f8fb43a0df42125a0.jpg" alt="Physics"">
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Edited code to make form in middle of page and put images at bottom of page (they will move on resize).

Comment: Its worked but both my images and the login form have positions. The images were supposed to be centred at the bottom of the page and the login form centred in the middle of the page. Any idea on how to solve this issue?

Comment: is the form the only thing on the page?

Comment: theres the header, login form and the images

Comment: I mean, are you going to add anything else to the page (anything not already there)?

Comment: Also, it seems you want the images at the bottom of the page but not moving when you resize the window. When you code, the images won't always be on the bottom in EVERY screen unless they move when you resize. If you want the images at the bottom of a given screen resolution only then just position the images that way (use top: __px;).

Comment: I'm not going to put anything else on the page, and i've been trying to make my website dynamic but hasn't been going too well